# Spring REST authentication with key

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC 4.2.5 RESTful back-end and I am adding Spring Security 4.0.4, with Tomcat 8, and using JDK 1.8, and Hibernate 5.1.x.

I'm looking to do some stateless Spring Security with REST services.  The way I envision this, is that some entity requesting a URL is passing in a key as part of the URL.  The key is either part of the url as either a path variable:

```
http://my.restful.url:8080/api/someapi/{data}/key/{your security key}
```

or as part of a querystring:

```
http://my.restful.url:8080/api/someapi?data={data}&key={your security key}
```

As long as the key is passed in.   The controller looks something like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/someapi/{data}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
 public @ResponseBody SomeEntity doSomeWork(@PathVariable("data") String data, @PathVariable("key") String key) throws Exception
 {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User user = null;
    if (principal instanceof User)
    {
        user = ((User) principal);
    }
    SomeEntity someEntity = service.doSomeWork(data);
    return someEntity;=
}
```

I have used a pre-authentication filter before, but I don't think I can do that here.  I want to configure this, so I can call the database and lookup a user with that key to see if it even exists.

I have done a CustomUserDetailsService before where I took a cookie as a token, did a lookup on that, got the username, and then did a database lookup to get that user and their roles.  Then I could assign that user the proper roles that they have.

I have a spring-security.xml file, and I'm just looking how I can configure that.   I have the basics of a file down so, each URL is locked down to a user role.

```
  <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">

        <csrf disabled="true"/>

         <!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->
         <intercept-url pattern="/someapi/**" access="hasRole('WEB')" />      
  </http>
```

I realize that there are multiple ways to implement Spring Security 4.  The final way has yet to be determined.   I don't know if we'll use AWS IAM, or some other LDAP like OpenAM, I have no idea if we'll just use database authentication.

Not sure what the final Identity Manager will finally be.
So, this is only a temporary measure to make sure that only certain users can see certain web url's.   That's all.  I'd like to not user username and password, but rather some key which I can add to the user table, and do a lookup on.

Any help would be much appreciated.    Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be passing secure keys as URL paths *or* query parameters. URLs regularly get logged and if those logs get compromised in any way then security to your application is also compromised.

Comment: Do you know how many third party sites I have used that are doing the same thing?  They assign you a key, and then you pass it in with the URL as a querystring or path variable.   So, I understand the concern, but again, this is only a temporary solution to secure a URL.   I don't know ultimately what type of security measure is going to be taken.   I am not the CTO, and I don't make those "executive" decisions.

Comment: If your company is okay with being only as secure as some third party sites, I'd get that in writing. I guess it depends on where the buck stops where you work. At my job, if the security of the application was compromised due to my implementation, I would be fired without reference before the CTO was. I'm not confident my CTO would take a bullet for me. But then again my CTO isn't actively involved in lower level design decisions.

Comment: Cory ... there is a small startup I working for with 6 people, of which I am 1 one 2 senior software developers.   This is not some gigantic multi-billion dollar company where I am in charge of securing this massive API, and essentially we have ONE api for now to secure with the possibility of TWO coming down the road.  I am not full-time, or even paid at this point.   They are in the process of looking for a CTO.  With that being said, I do not know what direction the CTO will want to go when he comes on board ... whenever that is.

Comment: So .... I don't think I am going to spend days on a massive project choosing a security design and schema technology and implement a full-proof security plan with the possibility that they may go in a totally different direction very shortly.   Hence ... it just needs to show we have security.   If you'd like to discuss it further, you can reach me at:  tom@tomholmes.net ....     BTW ... thanks for not answering my question at all.

Comment: Sorry - I hope my comments didn't come off as attacking you, I didn't mean them that way. The level of security implemented is a design decision: 100% security doesn't exist anywhere. I was just trying to show my perspective of why I felt the proposed level of security here was unwise, but it depends of course on what you are doing and you are the only person who can make that decision. Also: I didn't answer your question because I'm not qualified to, not because I'm intentionally withholding knowledge.